# Upload blob file to cloudinary using React, Cloudinary Bad Request 400

Tags: reactjs, upload, base64, blob, cloudinary

I am trying to crop images from the selected files so, it is getting converted into blob,

Now i am facing difficulty in uploading them to the cloudinary , as it says its a bad request and
not getting uploaded.

The code goes like,

```
const blobToBase64 = (blob) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        resolve(reader.result);
      };
    });
  };
const uploadFilesToCloud = async () => {
    const data = new FormData();
    for (let i = 0; i < imageUrls.length; i++) {
      console.log("This is from within the loop: imageURL", imageUrls[i]);

      blobToBase64(new Blob([imageUrls[i]])).then(async (myFile) => {
        console.log(typeof myFile); // res is base64 now
        console.log("This is from within the loop file BaseToBase64", myFile);

        data.append("file", myFile);
        data.append("upload_preset", "theVegCakeShop");

        const res = await fetch(
          "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dpurb6xes/image/upload",
          {
            method: "Post",
            body: data,
          }
        );
        const response = await res.json();
        console.log(response.secure_url);

        setImages((prev) => [...prev, response.secure_url]);
      });
    }
  };
```

Output is

```
This is from within the loop: imageURL blob:http://localhost:8888/7fbda7a7-e4d5-4716-a888-c9dbd80cd4fb
string
This is from within the loop file BaseToBase64 data:application/octet-stream;base64,YmxvYjpodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0Ojg4ODgvN2ZiZGE3YTctZTRkNS00NzE2LWE4ODgtYzlkYmQ4MGNkNGZi
POST https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dpurb6xes/image/upload 400 (Bad Request)
undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of actually converting the imageUrl into blob and then base64. Directly convert the imageUrl into Base64.

Using the following function.

```
    const getBase64FromUrl = async (url) => {
    const data = await fetch(url);
    const blob = await data.blob();
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        const base64data = reader.result;
        resolve(base64data);
      };
    });
  };
```

And then in your code.

```
for (let i = 0; i < imageUrls.length; i++) {
      const finalImage = await getBase64FromUrl(imageUrls[i]);
        data.append("file", myFile);
    data.append("upload_preset", "theVegCakeShop");

    const res = await fetch(
      "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dpurb6xes/image/upload",
      {
        method: "Post",
        body: data,
      }
    );
    const response = await res.json();
    console.log(response.secure_url);

    setImages((prev) => [...prev, response.secure_url]);

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your base64 data looks wrong, it's mimetype is `application/octet-stream`, it should be something like `image/png` for example. So it looks like the image URL you are passing is not really an image - once you start decoding actual images, it should upload fine.

Comment: can you please see and suggest me where i should make changes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71851549/covert-blob-url-to-file-or-base64-to-upload-to-cloudinary

Comment: can you send a sample of an image you're converting to base64 pls?

Comment: Thank you Tom , Based on your comment i worked it out. and seemed like i didn't have to convert the image url to blob before converting it into the base64. So now i am converting it directly from imageUrl to Base64. Now everything is working just fine . Thank you .